# How to remotely connect to my MongoDB in my server with java?

Tags: java, mongodb, server, firewall, database

I want to use my MongoDB on my server from a java application on my laptop.
this is my ufw setting

```
aran@Aran:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
27017                      ALLOW       1.234.56.78
27017                      ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27017 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

At first I only had this rule:

```
27017                      ALLOW       1.234.56.78
```

Where 1.234.56.78 is my Ip address but it didn't work so I added this rule:

```
27017                      ALLOW       Anywhere
```

But That didn't help either.

Here is my java code:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(Level.OFF);
MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://123.45.67.89:27017");
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
MongoDatabase CaptionBotUsers = mongoClient.getDatabase("CaptionBotUsers");
//CaptionBotUsers.createCollection("users", new CreateCollectionOptions().autoIndex(true));
MongoCollection<Document> users = CaptionBotUsers.getCollection("users");
long found = users.count(Document.parse("{_id : " + Long.toString(user.getId()) + "}"));
```

But I get:

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=123.45.67.89:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
```

For the Last line of the code(*long found...*)

So how can I fix this?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/

Comment: Have you checked *bind_ip* setting on MongoDB configuration file? It should allow external connections (i.e: 0.0.0.0) -> https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.2/reference/configuration-options/#bind_ip

Comment: Have you started with?
 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: yes @cricket_007

Comment: Are you sure mongodb is actually running then? And you've configured that port? The Firewall is open if you open the port from anywhere

Comment: Try running `sudo netstat -tupln | grep mongod` to see what IP and port mongo is listening on

Comment: If your MongoDB server is running on a public cloud you might have to configure the firewall there too.

Comment: it's on my VPS.

Answer (score 0):

From MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp), it states that in some installations by default in only listens local connections (127.0.0.1).

To connect remotely you need to configure a public accesible interface in **/etc/mongod.conf**:

```
...
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: <your-ip>, 127.0.0.1
...
```

Comment: Binding to that specific IP doesn't open it to the client, does it? `0.0.0.0` might be preferred

Comment: Didn't work. btw! can you please edit your answer so that my real Ip is not shown?@GonzaloMatheu

Comment: (reposting comment to delete public IP since I cannot edit)
@cricket_007 It allows clients to make MongoDB connections to that IP. If you have several network interfaces, you can have a more fine-grained control on who you allow you to connect. I almost always use 0.0.0.0, I must say.

Comment: If *bindIp* value is/was *127.0.0.1* you will not be able to connect from outside, so you have to change it to allow external connections. It might not solve your problem, but you will need it.